# Resource Change Plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created an RCP application which detects resource change in its own view by extending **CommonNavigator**.

```java
public abstract class NavigatorView extends CommonNavigator  implements
    IResourceChangeListener {
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
 super.createPartControl(parent);
 hookResourceChangeCommand(); // my resource tracking function.
 }
}
```

But now I need to create a plugin for this which detects resource change in project explorer in eclipse itself. I cannot create a view now and I need to detect already existing view. How should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please completely remove the view that you created. You should not do anything in the UI, if you want to track resource changes, as resources are part of the workspace concept, and the workspace is generally headless (that is without UI).

Instead use the code below (taken from the [resource change listener tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html)):

```java
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
   IResourceChangeListener listener = new IResourceChangeListener() {
      public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
         System.out.println("Something changed!");
      }
   };
   workspace.addResourceChangeListener(listener);

   //... some time later one ...
   workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually this is the same reference I have gone through too. Earlier I was writing this listener in a view code. Now, since there wont be any views, I only have the activator class. Can you please tell me where should I put this listener ?

Comment: You can put it in the activator of your plugin (and then have the start level of your plugin changed, so that it is always started).