# Plugin development: listener to resource change in plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing plugin of graph that use the objects in the current file that open. If I change the file that open, I want the graph will update. 
Now, I am using setFocus() method in my class that extends ViewPart, and update the graph in every call to this function. 
This is not what I want, I want to update the graph only when the resource change.
I found this link:

[link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165214/resource-change-plugin-for-eclipse)

[This is like my question, but there is no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244316/how-to-add-iresourcechangelistener-in-eclipse-plugin)

I need to put the following code in the activator.java file of my plugin?:

```
   IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
   IResourceChangeListener listener = new IResourceChangeListener() {
      public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
         System.out.println("Something changed!");
      }
   };
   workspace.addResourceChangeListener(listener);

   //... some time later one ...
   workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(listener);
```

If I need to add this code, where to put it? In which method to put it in the activator.java file?
If not, what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the listener in the view part `createPartControl`.

The activator is not a suitable place to set up listeners as it is only run when some other code in the plugin runs.

Comment: Don't forget to also remove the listener when the View is closed.

Comment: The listener is calling twice like in this question [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875766/iresourcechangelistener-being-called-twice-with-one-change). I am removeing the listener in the method dispose() (I saw in the API of IWorkbenchPart that there I need to deregister all listeners from the workbench). I didn't figure out why it's calling twice (I printed the event and it's org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace
 in both calls). In the first call it's even call the listener 3 times!

Comment: Also, the listener catch only changes in current file. But if I choose another file, the listener doesn't catch that I am in another file and the graph in the view, is the graph of the previous file I looked at, unless I change the new file and save it, then it's recognize the new file. Do you know which listener I need for this thing? Thank you very much!

Comment: The number of events you get can vary and includes events for the folder, project and workspace being changed as well as the files. Be sure to look at all the resource deltas in the event (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42562728/2670892))

Comment: I found out with the debugger that in every call of the listener. The Resource Delta is:the cachedResource in null and the children have project and the children of the project have folder and the children of the folder have file. In both calls the delta looks the same.. so what can I do?

Comment: @greg-449 , please can you help me? I really tried to find solution but I didn't find.

Comment: Ask a new question explaining exactly what you are doing, what you expected to see and what you are actually seeing.

Comment: Note that the resource change listener only tells you about files being added, removed or changed and only when saved. If what you really want to know is which file is currently selected in another view you use the selection service `ISelectionService`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137203/discussion-between-rog-and-greg-449).